# How to configure OpenVPN to update Bind9 entries for local domain?

Tags: openvpn, bind, internal-dns, dns-zone, dhcp-server

I have found an article describing how to configure dhcp3 server to update a Bind9 zone with the hostnames and assigned ip addresses.

I want to achieve the same effect, but inside a VPN subnet, where each VPN client will receive an IP address, and it's hostname/client-name will be added to the local domain zone.

However, OpenVPN seems to have it's own dhcp server, and I can't find anything about linking it to bind.

One solution would be to configure the VPN as a tap device, and bridge it to a virtual network interface on which to use the dhcp3 server. But this seems like overkill.

Is there a simpler, cleaner solution?

**UPDATE:**

Even that doesn't work. Somehow the dhcp server sees the DHCPDISCOVER request as comming from the tap0 MAC address, so when it sends a response, the VPN client doesn't get it:

```
Feb  7 00:41:22 vpn-server1 dhcpd[7601]: DHCPDISCOVER from fe:b4:3f:fe:9d:0e via tap0
Feb  7 00:41:23 vpn-server1 dhcpd[7601]: DHCPOFFER on 172.16.0.2 to fe:b4:3f:fe:9d:0e (vpn-server1) via tap0
```

ifconfig

```
tap0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet 172.16.0.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 0.0.0.0
    inet6 fe80::5c70:cea0:5619:ac47  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
    ether fe:b4:3f:fe:9d:0e  txqueuelen 100  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 95  bytes 14590 (14.2 KiB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

OpenVPN Server log:

```
Fri Feb  7 00:41:21 2020 MULTI: no dynamic or static remote --ifconfig address is available for Client-1/192.168.1.105:39069
Fri Feb  7 00:41:23 2020 Client-1/192.168.1.105:39069 PUSH: Received control message: 'PUSH_REQUEST'
Fri Feb  7 00:41:23 2020 Client-1/192.168.1.105:39069 SENT CONTROL [Client-1]: 'PUSH_REPLY,peer-id 1' (status=1)
```

Comment: **OpenVPN** does not use `DHCP` to configure the client, but an internal method. To update the DNS entry, you can configure a [--client-connect scipt](https://openvpn.net/community-resources/reference-manual-for-openvpn-2-4/#scripting-and-environmental-variables), which will use, e.g., the **common_name** and **ifconfig_pool_remote_ip** variables passed to the script to perform an appropriate `nsupdate`.

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz I will read more about nsupdate to be able to implement this. Could you add details and make it into an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I make a couple of assumptions on your **OpenVPN** and **Bind9** configuration, which simplify the configuration:

1. Both servers are running on the same host,
2. Bind9's zone allows [dynamic updates](https://bind9.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced.html#dynamic-update), which surely is the case if your **dhcpd** server is also updating the zone.
3. OpenVPN clients authenticate using TLS certificates, which have a **CN** equal to the DNS name you want to register, e.g. the DN on the certificate is `DC=com, DC=example, CN=client1.example.com`.

In order to register the address of a newly connected client, you need a simple script (let's call it `/etc/openvpn/update-dns`):

```sh
#!/bin/bash

/usr/bin/nsupdate -l <<EOF
del $common_name
add $common_name. 300 IN A $ifconfig_pool_remote_ip
send
EOF
```

and add it to the **OpenVPN** configuration:

```
script-security 2
learn-address /etc/openvpn/update-dns
```

**PS**: Your initial attempt using a **tap** interface and a real **dhcpd** to provide client addresses should also work, e.g. with a server configuration of:

```
server-bridge
dev tap0
ifconfig 172.16.0.2
# authentication options
```

and a client configuration:

```
client
dev tap0
# authentication options
```

and **Bind9** listening on `tap0`, a `dhclient -d tap0` called on the OpenVPN client will obtain an address. The change of **MAC** in the `DHCP` packets you observe are caused by **OpenVPN** acting as a DHCP proxy:

> If **–server-bridge** is used without any parameters (*my note: or with the **nogw** parameter*), it will enable a DHCP-proxy mode, where connecting OpenVPN clients will receive an IP address for their TAP adapter from the DHCP server running on the OpenVPN server-side LAN.

Source: [OpenVPN reference manual](https://openvpn.net/community-resources/reference-manual-for-openvpn-2-4/).

However I am note sure what's **OpenVPN**'s definition of server-side LAN.